# Implementing a leaderboard in a LibGDX game

Tags: android, libgdx, leaderboard

I have a libGDX game published and running on play store but I am facing problems in implementing leaderboards in the game. I have tried probably everything available on the Internet for this, example:

[Google Play Games Services in LibGDX](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Play-Games-Services-in-LibGDX)

[google play game services tutorial example](http://theinvader360.blogspot.in/2013/10/google-play-game-services-tutorial-example.html)

[how to setup google play game services in libgdx using android studio](https://chandruscm.wordpress.com/2015/12/30/how-to-setup-google-play-game-services-in-libgdx-using-android-studio)

I have gone through probably all the material from Google, have setup leaderboards, application id and achievement id and have published the game leaderboard via Google place console, however issue is I get struck mostly in all the tutorials or materials information provided in setting up the leaderboards.

Now I am trying again using the below link as myhave made my app in Android Studio and libGDX.

[how to setup google play game services in libgdx using android studio](https://chandruscm.wordpress.com/2015/12/30/how-to-setup-google-play-game-services-in-libgdx-using-android-studio/)

Now the vary basic issue with this tutorial and with others is that it says to clone the repository which has Android basic samples as below

[android-basic-samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples)

And then `import BaseGameUtils` at path `BasicSamples\libraries\BaseGameUtils`, however this project doesn't have BaseGameUtils Sample available.

Can anyone advice if there is any correct way of implementing Leaderboards using libGDX and Android studio and how to use BaseGameUtils. Is this an old tuts and if Google API is changed.

Comment: All of that is outdated. You should follow official Google Play Games docs: https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards

Comment: @Arctic45 , I am looking for an implementation in LibGDX itself .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many days of reading and struggle i was able to implement leaderboards in libGDX Game . a new detailed updated tutorial can be seen as in below link

https://www.versionpb.com/tutorials/step-step-tutorials-libgdx-basic-setup-libgdx/implementing-google-play-services-leaderboards-in-libgdx/